# Word for something that is protected or guarded? Must be a noun

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for something that is protected or guarded? The thing that is being protected doesn't have to necessarily be valuable, secret, or even hidden from view. It just has to be something that is guarded, and difficult to access. The word must be a noun.

For example,

> The King's horse was a _____. He allowed no one but himself to ride it.

I would offer what I have thought of so far but I can't even think of a word close to it...

Comment: A good next step would be to try an online thesaurus. Good starting words might be "treasure", "property", and "prerogative". Not that I'm suggesting those specific words as answers but that they might have some useful synonyms. If you do consult a thesaurus please edit your post and add your results.

Comment: I'd use '... [the] apple of his eye' here: precious, treasured, guarded. But it's a noun phrase rather than a noun.

Comment: Why are you restricted to a noun? There are many ways of saying this, but virtually all of them rely on an adjective or verb rather than noun.

Comment: @1006a I'm working on a concept in programming, and need to give the concept a descriptive but deliciously terse name. I'm trying to be consistent with all the other one-word concept names I've used.

Comment: Why am I tempted to say *protégé*? ;-)

Comment: There is a single word for 'that which is protected or guarded by a protector or guard'. It is their 'charge'. Whether you can use that will depend on the details of your programming concept. For example, if you have a class or interface called 'custodian', it might be OK to give it a property called 'charge'. But the word 'charge' has so many uses that it might equally be very confusing. Can you provide a little bit more info about your technical concept? Do you have a generic word for the 'guard' which guards the thing in question, for example?

Comment: @Drew You're tempted because it's similar to protectee, which is what the Secret Service of the United States calls the people it protects.

Comment: @ArchContrarian I have a static class, to which I can dynamically add "secure" methods. These methods may only be called if the currently logged in user is allowed to. These "secure methods" are what I am trying to give a name to. You already guessed what I am trying to do--have two sets of methods: one set is for the interface that is publicly accessible, and the other set is for sensitive transactions (the secure ones). "charge" might actually work, if you post it as an answer I might vote it as the answer

Answer (score 4):

A *ward* is the responsibility of a guardian.

A *charge* has a more general connotation of a responsibility laid on a responsible person; what is laid in a charge could be a person or a mission.

A *waif* is a helpless child without home or friends.

You could also consider nouning an adjective like *vulnerable*.

In terms of things that are wrapped in a protective coating or envelope, you might think about *payload* or *contents*.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `prize`. I know that you have not specified a contest, but `prize` captures both (a) a thing of value and (b) a thing worth striving for (and by extension, worth guarding until it is "won")

While `prize` is a noun, it may also be used as a verb, as in **regard highly; think much of** ("We prize his vast knowledge of words")

http://www.onelook.com/?w=prize&ls=a

Comment: And something that you *take* or *hold*, as in the French verb **prendre**.

Answer (score 2):

**Chattel** might fit the bill.

> - (in general use) a personal possession.
> - *LAW* an item of property other than real estate.

(google)

. . . that is, if you don't mind  one of the alternate usages:

> - slave

(Merriam-Webster)

Even then, though, as 1006a commented, it's hard to nail down the "protected" part with using an adjective. Like . . . well, "protected".

Answer (score 1):

It's not typically used as a noun, but "coveted" is technically usable as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like one of the anthropological meanings of [***taboo***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/taboo). It's not a very well-known usage, but it might suit your purposes. From the *American Heritage Dictionary*, via thefreedictionary.com (bolding added):

> *n.* 2.
>   a. A prohibition, especially in Polynesia and other South Pacific islands, excluding something from use, approach, or mention because of its sacred and inviolable nature.
>   b. **An object, word, or act protected by such a prohibition.**

I think the connotations work especially well with your example—the horse is reserved for the use of the king, simultaneously exalted and forbidden, and presumably protected by means of custom and fear of reprisal rather than through more physical means (the horse isn't kept in a safe).

Answer (score 1):

The U.S. Secret Service calls a person it protects a **protectee**.  You could use "protected" as a noun.

However, these people, animals, or objects that need protection are "targets" of others, presumably.  That's another possibility.